# I am not able to install Visual c++ 2008 Express

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am not able to install Visual c++ 2008 Express. I have this message: "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition with SP1 - ENU has encountered a problem during setup. Setup did not complete correctly." This is the error log: http://www.filedropper.com/logs

Comment: please include the pertinent log entries in your post rather than using a shady file hoster.

Answer (score -1):

returned 8004036e/ error code 80004005

Install MSDN Help manualy ... and see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/884461/en-us

> A work around exists for this problem, but you can only use this
>   workaround if the following conditions are true: •You are experiencing
>   the problem that is mentioned in the “Symptoms” section.  •The
>   8004036e hexadecimal error value is returned for the CreateTransaction
>   function.
>
> You can verify whether this hexadecimal error value was returned by
>   checking the log file. To work around this problem, follow these
>   steps:
>   1.Search for the Rgstrtn.lck file on your computer.
>
> This file may be located in the TEMP folder or in any subfolder of the
>   TEMP folder, or it may be located in the following folder: System
>   Drive:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft
>   Help
>   2.If the Rgstrtn.lck file exists, move the Rgstrtn.lck file to another folder.
>   3.If any folders exist in the following folder, move the folders to another location: System Drive:\Documents and Settings\All
>   Users\Application Data\Microsoft Help Note System Drive is a
>   placeholder for the drive where the operating system of your computer
>   is installed.
>
> Do not rename the folders that are mentioned in the "Workaround"
>   section. If you rename the folders that are present in the System
>   Drive \Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft
>   Help folder, you cannot work around this problem. The code verifies
>   the existence of any folder regardless of the name in the System
>   Drive\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft Help
>   folder. If this folder contains any folders, you cannot work around
>   this problem.

may be help ...

Comment: Your answer leaves a lot to be desired.

Comment: @Ramhound “Have no fear of perfection - you'll never reach it.” ― Salvador Dalí. Thank you for the opportunity to sneer at himself)).

Comment: You offer no instruction. **When I made the comment your answer was a single statement and did not answer the author's question.**

Comment: @Ramhound For some time now I'm doing the plugs in place of an answer. Questions that I like to answer is often closed. And then respond to them there is no way ... only comment ...